# Is it possible to add ethernet interface in iPAD external accessory device?

Tags: ipad, usb, mfi, ether

We wanted to add an ethernet interface to our MFi accessory.
First we want to know is it possible to add ethernet interface in an MFi accessory which uses iAP2 External Accessory Session to communicate with app present in the iOS device via lightning USB interface?
And, Does the iAP2 protocol support ethernet emulation of MFI accessory to the iOS device?

Answer (score 0):

iOS usb ethernet interface may only enabled for iPhone CarPlay mode.
The interface is not list in USB Device Descriptor.
You can check USB Device Descriptor by the command in Ubuntu after attaching iPad:

> lsusb -v